# Simple query performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Let's say i have 4 Tables A,B,C and D
[image]

What is the best way to get list of B to be in a dropdown list. 
Condition is that each record should have associated list of D1
so that if B has no D1 records i should not show it in the dropdown list

**D1 is a child class of D**

How i did it:

```
// number 2 to specify the selected A Table normally it's a variable
var b_Per_A = Uow.B.GetAll().Where(x => x.A_Id == 2).ToList();
var b_list = new List<B>();
foreach (var b in b_list)
{
    var d =
        Uow.D1.GetAll().Where(x => x.C.B_Id == b.Id);
    if (!d.IsNullOrEmpty()) // extension method that checks if a collection is null or empty
    {
        b_list.Add(b);
    }
}
```

It works but it's slow

UPDATE:

The signature of `GetAll()` is

```
IQueryable<T> GetAll();
```

UPDATE 2:

My Model is

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<B> ChildBs { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public A ParentA { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<C> ChildCs { get; set; }
}
public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public B ParentB { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<D> ChildDs { get; set; }
}

public class D
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public C ParentC { get; set; }
}

public class D1 : D
{
    /// other properties
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use stored procedure rather than linq?

Comment: Do you have navigation properties on your entity objects? I.e. `C.ChildDs` and `D.ParentC`

Comment: Dont use `GetAll()` and then filter it. Filter it directly otherwise, if you have 1000 records it will get all 1000 records and then you are trying to filter which will impact some performance.

Comment: @Thennarasan Not true if `GetAll()` returns an `IQueryable`

Comment: @ChrisPickford yes i do have navigation properties

Comment: @Thennarasan yes it returns IQueryable

Comment: @Maro can you post the navigation properties code, to create and check?

Comment: It's easy to write in sql -> `select * from b where exists (select 1 from c where b_id = b.id and exists (select 1 from d where c_id = c.id))`. I'll leave the translation to linq for someone that has more experience with entity framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you've confirmed you have navigation properties on your entity classes, this could be achieved in a single expression:

```
var result = Uow.B.GetAll()
    .Where(b => 
        b.ParentA.Id == 2 &&
        b.ChildCs.Any() &&
        b.ChildCs.SelectMany(c => c.ChildDs).Any())
    .ToList();
```

This will push the filtering to your database rather than doing it in memory and should be a lot more efficient.

Also, I'm assuming that a parent navigation property will never be `null` and that child collections are always initialized.

[Example here](https://gist.github.com/chrispickford/fcc02e45b693c81829985c8b9169ad04)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will give it a try, just the term of Parent/child is confusing since there are no inheritance.

Comment: @Maro If you add the entity model definitions to your question, I'll update the answer to match your property names.

Comment: Your code works fine and i got all results, however i made a mistake forgot to mention that class D is a kind of abstract class and i'm looking for one of it's childeren let's say D1.
If you have a solution it would be great otherwise i will except your answer since it was my mistake to forgot it. I will update my question

Comment: Ok i will try to copy your model and modify it

Answer (score -3):

put your *var d = Uow.D.GetAll().Where(x => x.C.B_Id == b.Id);* outside of your foreach. I also recommend you to use IEnumerable/ICollection instead of List and use for loop instead of foreach. Indexed looping is faster.

Comment: so if you put it out of the loop, how he going to use it to check with `b.id`? more explanation needed